# Carregar página e no final clicar em um botão de forma automática

Tags: javascript

Gostaria que ao carregar a página fosse clicado de forma automática no botão **fileToUpload**, no seguinte código:

```
<body>

  <form name="form5" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Upload.aspx">

    <div>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
    </div>
  </form>
<!-- fiz esse código abaixo mas não funciona-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.form5.getElementById("fileToUpload").click();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: De momento estás a utilizar Javascript puro ou jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível crossbrowser por questões de segurança. Os browsers são cada vez mais restritivos ao acesso a ficheiros.

A única maneira de abrir essa caixa de seleção de ficheiros é na sequência de uma ação do utilizador. Ou seja, se houver um evento na página é possivel "transferi-lo" para que se abra a janela (exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7j0j9qpu/1/).

Mas não vai funcionar caso seja um evento criado sem ação do utilizador (exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7j0j9qpu/ que não funciona em Chrome 46 em mac).

Answer (score 0):

Usando os scripts abaixo é possível executar o evento de click em um `input` do tipo `file`, porém somente em alguns browser com versões antigas, como mencionados [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905288/which-browsers-support-triggering-click-event-on-inputtype-file-elements) do SOen. Portanto não irá ajuda-lo mas que fique como referência caso alguém precise.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileToUpload').trigger('click');
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();
});
```

Comment: testaste esse código? não funciona para mim... http://jsfiddle.net/7j0j9qpu/

Comment: @Sergio aqui funcionou... https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/7spdp9xm/, porque será que não funcionou ai ?

Comment: No teu exemplo usas um `button`, no meu uso `input[type=file]`, acho que o browser impede por razões de segurança. Eu estou a usar Chrome em Mac.

Comment: @Sergio então desta forma é inviável, irei tentar outras alternativas.